# WebService Response Validation Case sensitive

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I can call the web both in SoapUI and in Eclipse and each returns a result. The problem with it is that in the request an item has been defined, for example, as "userCity", but in the response as "usercity". This means there is no check on Case sensitivity from SoapUI and Eclipse. A general validation of WSDL brings here also no help.

Is there any way to check the response of the WSDL against the request? If I call the request with Axis2 and Java directly it never returns a result and I would like to recognize such problems before.

Comment: Please add the code in question and explain what you want the code to do and what is not working as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI provides a "Contain" assertion, where you can make your validation case insensitive (if that is what you need). See the picture bellow.
[image: The case insensitive valiation]

If you need to compare the service response with the service request I would recommend a Script assertion (with custom groovy script).

Comment: No thats not exactly that what I want. I want that SoapUI dont give me an Response if the wording in Request and Response is different. Is there no existing way to perform this validation? I havent used groovy script before.